# Need sql query to pull back data that meets several groups of criteria from same table in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write an sql query that will pull back the data that meets several groups of criteria from the same table. The easiest way to describe is to imagine using an SQL "in" clause but instead of the internals of that clause being "or"s joining the parameters you want it to match it is instead an "and".

I attempted to use count to verify the correct amount of data was pulled back for each "in" statement but the count can't always be trusted due to other entries being similar for each column.

A sample table might be this:

```
id   count  animal
---  -----  ------
1      5    puppy
1      6    cat
1      6    puppy
```

So, now I need a query that will pull back all entries with an id of 1 and a count of 5 and 6 and an animal of puppy and cat. I pretty much need to verify the entire path of the table entry to know I want to pull it back. Is there any built in function that can do this? Do I need to use a recursive CTE to dig deep after confirming that one set of criteria is met? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you Serg for the help with formatting the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right

```
with cnt as(
    select id
    from tbl
    where [count] in (5,6) and animal in ('puppy', 'cat')
    group by id
    having count(distinct[count])=2 and count(distinct animal)=2
)
select id, [count], animal
from tbl 
where id in (select id from cnt);
```

Comment: This seems to work. Turns out I only needed the internals of the recursive function to do what I needed. Thank you so much for your help. I am marking this as the right answer.

Comment: To be precise, this cte is not recursive. Oh , and definitley it should be `select id, [count], animal from tbl`, not cnt. Will correct it.

Comment: Oh awesome. Thank you so much! For the answering and the formatting. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = 1 and
      count in (5, 6) and
      animal in ('puppy', 'cat');
```

EDIT:

If you want them all in the same row, just rearrange the conditions:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = 1 and
      ( (count = 5 and animal = 'puppy') or
        (count = 6 and animal = 'cat')
      );
```

Comment: See above comment to Sam. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of confusing what you're looking for exactly but can you not use or's and ands?

```
select id, count, animal 
from table 
where id = 1 and
      (count = 5 or count = 6) and
      (animal = puppy or anmial = cat)
```

Comment: You need to use 2 sets of parentheses with this approach... Using `in` would be easier though.

Comment: So the tricky thing is I need to verify the fully justified path of each entry. So I need to make sure that the entry has (id = 1, count = 5, animal = puppy) and (id=1, count = 6, animal = cat). If both of these fully justified entries aren't in the table then I don't want to pull back anything. This is why I can't use in.

Comment: I agree Gordons answer is easier I just wanted to spell out the query so he could understand how it works. I'll edit my answer with parentheses though.

Comment: The code posted will only return results based on what you specify. Do you only want results when count is 5 when the animal is puppy and count is 6 when the animal is cat?

Comment: So if I use the query provided on the table above then I will get all 3 rows returned but I only want the first two. I need the fully qualified column path of (id = 1, count = 5, animal = puppy) and (id=1, count = 6, animal = cat). Using ors is tricky because it could wrongfully pull back some entries. Also, thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: So change it to count = 5 and animal = puppy OR count = 6 and animal = cat?

Comment: So this definitely verifies the path better but could sometimes give me only 1 entry returned. I either need it to match all criteria and get all the rows back or nothing at all. Could I perform a count operation of the return rows making sure those two statements connect by the "or" returned something?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. We either need more info from the table you're pulling from or a better explanation. Its not a coincidence Gordan and myself are giving you almost the same answer. We're just giving you what you ask for :)